# Identify these dice with fists and half-black & half-white mask

Tags: dice, product-identification

I stumbled across this die the other day.

[image: There are 5 dice. The first dice has a half-black & half-white mask in the center and a symbol 2, 6, 6, and a star in the corner. The second dice shows a single fist in the center. The third dice shows 2 fists in the center. The fourth dice shows a half-black & half-white mask in the center and a symbol 2, 4, 4, and a star in the corner. The fifth dice shows a half-black & half-white mask in the center and a symbol 1, 3, 3, and an empty space in the corner.]

The missing image of the 6th side is another double fist.

Can anyone help me identify what game this is for?

Comment: Solely as a matter of form, how did you come by this dice (and thus think it (might) be from an RPG)?

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 15):

#### These are the dice for Deathstroke from *DC Dice Masters*.

[image]

It is published and sold by [Wiz Kids](http://wizkids.com/dicemasters/justice-league/), and more info about the game is available [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/138649/dc-comics-dice-masters-justice-league) at Board Game Geek,

Comment: @From That’s another card from the game. Not a different set.

Comment: @From No, they have the Starter rarity; Starter is not a set. If you look at the _exact_ page you link to you will notice they are on the same page as Deathstroke - Weapons Master

Comment: @Ryxer Unless I'm very much mistaken, we're dealing with one of those collectible card games, only with dice. For an expansion, you buy a starter set, and then as many "booster" packs as needed to (randomly) get the cards you actually want:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectible_card_game#Distribution